# Python with non-latin-1 PYTHONHOME path

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, latin1

In my case I embedded Python into my application. When the path of my application contains a non-latin-1 character *Py_Initialize* calls exit(1) internally (*more information later*).

**So I checked if can reproduce this with the standard interpreter executable.**

Python-2.7.x on Windows doesn't seem to work when the path of PYTHONHOME contains a character outside of latin-1 charset. The problem is that the module *site* could not be found and imported. Since umlauts seem to work, what is the actual limitation here? Is just latin-1 supported? Why does it work on OSX then?

```
C:\Users\ъ\Python27\python.exe    // fails to start (KOI8-R)
         ^
C:\Users\ġ\Python27\python.exe    // fails to start (latin-3)
         ^
C:\Users\ä\Python27\python.exe    // works fine (latin-1)
         ^
```

Any ideas?

**Background:**

I haven't stepped through the code yet but Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 also behave differently when *site* is not available. Py 2.6 just prints a message, Py 2.7 rejects to start.

```
static void
initsite(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    m = PyImport_ImportModule("site");
    if (m == NULL) {
        ...

        // Python 2.7 and later
        exit(1);

        // Python 2.6 and prior
        PyFile_WriteString("'import site' failed; traceback:\n", f);
    }
    ...
}
```

Python **2.7**: https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Python/pythonrun.c#L725

Python **2.6**: https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Python/pythonrun.c#L705

Comment: Have you tried using Python 3 instead? They redid the Unicode handling, and it's much cleaner. My recommendation is actually to use 3 whenever you can, and 2 only if you have to.

Comment: In Python 3 it (should) work/s, yes. I have to stick with Python 2 because this is the version we embedded in our software, this will change in the future though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you "embed" Python in your app? calling it from C/C++ ? what is the mechanism you use? And do you set the PYTHONHOME? if so how do you set it? As a side note the behaviour of OS FS wrt to unicode paths varies quite a bit on Windows, Mac and Linux/POSIX. And the way to deal with this in CPython 2 needs a bit of fiddling at times... Though I did wrestle with it a few times successfully

Comment: Using *Py_Initialize, ...*  from the C API. I tried *PYTHOMHOME* and the corresponding C functions (*Py_SetPath*, *Py_SetPythonhome*, ...) with no success. Btw, Python 2.7 (without being embedded) doesn't work either if installed at the given paths.

Comment: MS Windows differs from OS X in that the fundamental character set is UTF-16 there. For backward code, it also provides an "ANSI" API, which uses single byte strings but which isn't able to represent the whole Unicode range. I'm pretty sure Python 2 will never be upgraded to use the fully Unicode-capable win32 API, so any hassle is futile unless you at least upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that internally, Python2 processes everything as byte strings in the platform system encoding which is (in western europe) CP1252 a variant of Latin-1. So ther is no surprise that it cannot correctly process a PYTHONHOME path containing other characters

But, when I was younger, I was used to the good old 8.3 format of MS/DOS files...

I can still see (and use them) in a Windows 7 box with `DIR /X`  in a console (CMD.EXE) window. This format only use ASCII uppercase characters and tilda (`~`), so it could be used as a workaround : just declare the 8.3 path in the environment variable PYTHONHOME, and start python with that 8.3 path.

BTW, it is advisable for PYTHONHOME to use a path that contains neither special characters, nore spaces. It could work, but it could cause problems with other modules

Comment: I would totally agree if it would work on a russian Windows because they have the corresponding system codepage (guess its CP125**1**). But there it fails as well.

Comment: Just for completeness: the console codepage is 866 for a russian OS

Comment: If 8.3 names are missing, check whether they're disabled: `fsutil behavior query Disable8dot3 C:`. Note that enabling 8.3 names will only affect new files subsequently created, not existing files. You could also try using `mklink` to create an ASCII-only hard link, symbolic link, or junction.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [`PyImport_ImportModule` function version 2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/import.c#l2139) gives this definition:

```
PyObject *
PyImport_ImportModule(const char *name)
{
    PyObject *pname;
    PyObject *result;

    pname = PyString_FromString(name);
    if (pname == NULL)
        return NULL;
    result = PyImport_Import(pname);
    Py_DECREF(pname);
    return result;
}
```

While looking at the [`PyImport_ImportModule` function version 3.5](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/import.c#l1251) gives the same except with

```
pname = PyUnicode_FromString(name);
```

instead of

```
pname = PyString_FromString(name);
```

You can look at [the code for `PyString_FromString`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l114) and [the code for `PyUnicode_FromString`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l1881) but it seems clear that python 2 does not use unicode and python 3 does, but I have not been able to find how/where exactly this leads to the behavior you describe.

The [`PyImport_Import(module_name)` function (version 2.7)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/import.c#l2852) only uses `module_name` like so:

```
r = PyObject_CallFunction(import, "OOOOi", module_name, globals,
                          globals, silly_list, 0, NULL);
```

passing on the responsibility...

Comment: Just some background FYI: Python 2 does Unicode, but the Unicode handling was completely redone for Python 3. Python 2 used a "best guess" method of decoding, and if it guessed wrong, all hell would break loose. Python 3 treats Uncode strings as strings, and encoded Unicode as byte arrays, forcing you to explicitly handle conversion if necessary.

Comment: I expect the issue been located somewhere in **PyImport_Import**. I guess the lookup for directories with unicode characters in their path fails. As mentioned, I haven't debugged it though. At least latin-1 is still supported at this stage.